# Making the outer-edges of a UIBezierPath semi-transparent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, transparent, uibezierpath, line-drawing

I am currently drawing a UIImage within a UIBezierPath like so:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);
UIBezierPath *polygonPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

CGPoint curPoint = [self originalPoint:[[drawArray objectAtIndex:0]CGPointValue]];

// set the starting point for the lines
[polygonPath moveToPoint:curPoint];

// go through each point in drawArray and add it to polygonPath
for(NSInteger i = 1; i < [drawArray count]; i++) {
    curPoint = [self originalPoint:[[drawArray objectAtIndex:i]CGPointValue]];
    // scale point
    curPoint = CGPointMake(curPoint.x, curPoint.y);

    [polygonPath addLineToPoint:curPoint];
}

[polygonPath closePath];

[polygonPath addClip];

[image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
```

It works great, however I'd like to have "smooth edges", slightly transparent, for the image, as I'm drawing it on top of another image...  Right now the edges are pretty rough.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As you are drawing on the image. So I suggest you to use following code...

Where YourImageis the UIImage on which you are drawing line.

```
[[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:YourImage] set];
```

[For More Visit this reference](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html)

Hope, this will help you...